# How to open mht file via R?

Tags: r, mhtml

I met a problem to open mht files in R. There is an approach in which first I need to open it in Excel then save as `.xlsx` and after that read it in R.

But this way doesn't correspond to my requirements as soon as I need the program which must work automatically (no manual work needed).
But unfortunately I didn't found in the Internet how to do this.

Can someone advise me the way in which I can open file with `mht` format with some data in R?

Comment: Can you share one of your mhtml file? Without the data, it would be difficult for us to help.

Comment: @ekoam unfortunately I cannot because I'm not able to generate this kind of files meanwhile the file I have is a top secret file thus I cannot share it.

Comment: Then the best advice that I can give is to try perhaps the `xml2` package. Read its documentation for more details. If you can create an mhtml file with only the structure and some dummy data to thorouly illustrate your problem, we can give better suggestions.

Comment: @ekoam, the problem is I cannot create this kind of files even with dummy data. Otherwise I would share it with you. I will try `xml2` package. Maybe I will found something apropriate for my task.